# What are logistics like for a solo skier visiting Salt Lake City/Park City?

Tags: solo-travel, utah, skiing, salt-lake-city, park-city

I've decided I'd like to go to Utah this year to do some skiing and hopefully score some good powder days. I will be traveling by myself. My primary interest is to ski Alta, but were the logistics to work out such that it were easy, I might be interested to try other mountains in the area (Park City, etc.)

I would be flying into Salt Lake City. I've read up on the various transit options on the web (like UTA, private shuttle companies, etc) but I have no idea what it's actually like for skiers in the SLC and Park City areas to use these. In other words, is it feasible/pleasant to bring your equipment on public transit? I can see online that it is *allowed*, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea/pleasant experience. (Much like in my home town you can bring your bike on city buses, but by and large you'll wish you hadn't.) If at all possible, I would prefer to avoid renting a car (huge expense, not much use), but if doing so is going to make life/logistics substantially easier, I'm open to it. How do the savvy out-of-towners get around?

I've discovered from internet research and anecdotal reports that accommodations at Alta are scarce and "rustic." I'm not opposed to rustic, but I do like my privacy, and from the Alta website, it appears that many of the more affordable options are shared rooms. One resource I found suggested staying in SLC and commuting to the mountain. This seems horribly inconvenient on it's face (an hour each way on a bus with all my gear just sounds like a nightmare), but I'm open to the possibility that things work differently out there. Any secrets to know with respect to lodging?

In general, does anyone have any wisdom or suggestions to share on the logistics of a solo out-of-towner coming to the SLC/Park City area for the skiing?

Comment: I don't see any mention of "rustic" and the site as far as I can tell answers all questions regarding *Are there trains? Shuttle services? How do out-of-towners get around?*.  If you have looked at it you would have found map of ALTA town shuttle, lodging, transportation, etc.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the list of "transportation services" on alta.com. None of the resources there speak to what it's actually like to be on your own skiing in Utah without a car. Again, I'm looking for input based on *personal experience*. If you were coming to my hometown of Pittsburgh, PA, you could find lots of info on the web about how we have funiculars as part of our public transit system. As a native, from my *experience*, I could tell you that they're often broken down and not particularly useful for getting around the city, which you would not have gotten from the web resources.

Comment: *I'm looking for input based on personal experience* as you might imagine personal experience is exactly what it is *personal* and as such is likely to be closed as ["Primarily opinion based"](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) since every person is unique, with unique means, expectations, behaviors, etc

Comment: It sounds like you want to 'teach me how stack exchange works'. If you checked my profile, you'd see that I've got quite a bit of experience on other SE sites -- I know how SE works. I feel the question is appropriate and germane, in both content and format. I'm not asking for opinions. If someone asked a question like this about other places I've skied, I could easily provide useful hints. If you have a suggestion for how I should reword to improve the question, let me know, or make an edit. Otherwise, you've stated your objections and downvoted, but don't seem to have much else to offer.

Comment: I've already seen your profile before starting this discussion.  So let's get this cleared up: *Any secrets to know w/r/t lodging?* - What's your budget convenience factor target? *is it feasible/pleasant to bring your equipment on public transit?* - is it feasible sure, is it pleasant probably not but it's your equipment, so it usually is better tuned to you and so on and so forth.  The issue with your questions are basically that you leave too many options valid for any sort of definitive answer as it stands right now $1000/night will work too though you'd prefer not to spend it.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but I don't agree that further narrowing the question improves it. My budgets are somewhat flexible, as I've indicated (i.e. can afford to rent a car, would prefer not to,) and IME my cost/benefit priorities are mostly in line with other solo-travelling skiers I've met over the years. In response to your comments I've edited my question, and I'm happy with where it stands now and would like to wait and see what, if any, substantive answers show up.

Comment: Is it so hard to write Salt Lake City once entirely? This site targets a worldwide audience, not everyone knows what SLC stands for.

Comment: I would split this into 2 questions: Public transport and accomodation.

Comment: I would actually split this into 3 questions: public transport logistics, lodging tips, and general wisdom on going solo. I have a coworker who has a house in Snowbird, so I'll ask him about the former when he gets in.

Comment: Having completed my trip, I was hoping to come back and answer my own question, but I see it's been closed. Oh well.